# find out the elements visiblity

Tags: java, selenium

In my application , I have 3 listboxs, when I select any of the value in first listbox , the generate button is in progressing status (button is changed to rotating Symbol), the corresponding data is loaded in the  remaining listboxes, and the generate button should appear. For that condition , I wrote the code like

```
WebElement datarefresh_element = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 20)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated
 (By.id("butGenerate")));


if(datarefresh_element.isDisplayed()==true)
{

      System.out.println("Generate button is available");
}
    Select Dimension_selection = new Select  (driver.findElement(By.id("cbDimension")));
            Dimension_selection.selectByVisibleText("Net Flow");
            Dimension_selection.selectByVisibleText("Total Sales");
```

while executing the code, the if condition is satisfied ,but when I select the data in the second list box, the data is not selected. Could you please help / suggest , I need to use alternative expected condition in the driver for find the element.

Comment: Please edit your question add the code part where you are selecting data from the listbox

Comment: updated the selection criteria code as well

Comment: You say there are 3 dropdowns right? Then you should have three `Select` objects. I dont get the part as to why would you first select `Net Flow` and then try to select `Total Sales` from the same dropdown.

Comment: Based on the first listbox value  selection, the second Listbox is loaded 4 values , NetFlow , TotalSales ,and other two values, now i need to select the value in the second listbox only.

Comment: Do `selectByIndex` or `selectByValue` work?

Comment: I have used 3 options SelectByIndex , SelectByvalue,SelectVisiblebytext. but no use. driver is not selecting any values..

Comment: you have 3 values in 1 dropdown OR 3 diff. dropdowns?

Comment: 3 different listboxs . need to select  3 different values in the second dropdown. (scenario is  While selecting the value in the first listbox, the generate button is changed from button to progressing image, that time the other two selection boxes are disabled status. when data is loaded in the remaining boxes, , the progressing image changed to generate button, this is the confirmation of data loaded in the boxes, after that only i can select the values in the second list box.)

Comment: Any help and suggestion for this issue. i am struck with this option only

Answer (score 0):

The problem as you stated is answered in the comment section. There are 3 different list boxes, therefore you need 3 different element.

So you can use the same element for 3 different list boxes, It only represents the first list box.

Hopefully they also have there own unique name or id.

```
Select Dimension_selection2 = new Select  (driver.findElement(By.id("name of second box")));
Dimension_selection2.selectByVisibleText("Net Flow");
```

Comment: The you have to create a new select web element. Added example to my old response

Comment: i am using unique values only for identify the elements ,  While selecting the value in the first listbox, the generate button is changed from button to progressing image, that time the other two selection boxes are disabled status. when data is loaded in the remaining boxes, , the progressing image changed to generate button, this is the confirmation of data loaded in the boxes, after that only i can select the values in the second list box.

Comment: Ok. Then you need to wait for your next select clickable.  WebDriverWait wait; wait.until(ExpectedConditions.refreshed(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(by)));

Comment: it is not working. showing exception message like "element not visible: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated"

Comment: Good. Now we know more about your problem. No you can test this waiting function. wait.until(ExpectedConditions.refreshed(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(by)));

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are creating an object and if any modification/updation is done to it ... again create a new object for it.

```
WebElement dropDown1 = driver.findElement(By.id("dropDown1Id"))
Select dropDown1Selection = new Select(dropDown1);
dropDown1Selection.selectByVisibleText("dd1Value");

//Now as you have done the selection of dropDown1
//Add the code for wait so as the other dropdowns value are updated

//Create object of second drop down now - after the selection of dropdown1 item
WebElement dropDown2 = driver.findElement(By.id("dropDown2Id"))
Select dropDown2Selection = new Select(dropDown2);
dropDown2Selection.selectByVisibleText("dd2Value");

// If you are creating second dropdown object prior to updation (selection of an item from dropdown1) -- you will not to do the selection
```

Comment: Created new element only for the second dropdown. it is not selected the values in the listbox. first drop down is a single selection, second listbox is a multiple selection box.

Comment: Try to create the object once more>>WebElement dropDown2Second = driver.findElement(By.id("dropDown2Id")) >>Select dropDown2SelectionSecond = new Select(dropDown2Second );
>>dropDown2SelectionSecond .selectByVisibleText("dd2Value2");